# How do I make a 'ReadOnly' property in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, readonly

I have a property ("IsLatest") that I have set 'Read Only' to 'True'

Here's the XML:

```
<Column Name="IsLatest" Type="System.Boolean" DbType="Bit NOT NULL" IsReadOnly="true" CanBeNull="false" />
```

Why does the code-generator generate a public 'get' **AND 'SET'** accessor?

Also, is there a way to have it *not* generate a SET for a read-only property (what a novel idea)?

NOTE: I'm using V2008 SP1 with .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: Can I re-ask the question? Are you using 3.5SP1? the SP1 may be important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've added my successful workaround to the bottom of this answer.

This is strange... but, if I set the "Access" property to **anything other than 'Public'**, the "set" goes away:

With "Access=Public" and "ReadOnly=True":

```
public bool IsLatest
{
    get
    {
        return this._IsLatest;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._IsLatest != value))
        {
            this.OnIsLatestChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._IsLatest = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("IsLatest");
            this.OnIsLatestChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

With "Access=Protected" and "ReadOnly=True":

```
protected bool IsLatest
{
    get
    {
        return this._IsLatest;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this bug exists (for me at least?) but if I get this to work (public, and readonly), I'll update this answer.

EDIT: Here's the sad workaround:

I've removed the property from my DBML file, and simply added my own "partial" class and set the column myself:

```
public partial class ServicerData
{
    private bool _IsLatest = default(bool);

    [Column(Storage = "_IsLatest", AutoSync = AutoSync.Always, DbType = "Bit NOT NULL", IsDbGenerated = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public bool IsLatest
    {
        get
        {
            return this._IsLatest;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not what I want to do, but there seems to be no other way.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I've just checked, and it **didn't** generate a setter... are you using 3.5SP1?

---

If you are doing it by hand, I think you can; you simply use the Storage attribute-property (on `ColumnAttribute`) to point it at the field when updating (the get satisfies the query requirements)..

Comment: Well, the issue is that I don't want the compiler to allow someone 'setting' the field when they do a "new". - Interesting that yours didn't generate a set.

Comment: BTW: I'm using V2008 SP1 with .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: I'm also seeing this with VS2010, .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

How will Linq to Sql be able to assign a value to this property if there's no setter? Meaning if it gets data back from the Database, be it via a Linq query, or a result from a Store Procedure, Linq has to be able to create these objects for you based on those results. If there's no set property, it can't do that.

Comment: The setter should be protected in this case.

Comment: re ho it will set it? ColumnAttribute (and the meta-model) allows you to specify the Storage property as the private field.